# FTP file name and path error while uploading and downloading using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, download, ftp, filepath

I'm trying to implement file transfer using PHP.

I'm getting the following errors:-

1. Using Html form to upload a file. PHP file to fetch the file using
   $_files. How do I get the original file name with extension from the
   php object? basename method gives a different name. 
   I tried uploading a .txt file. It gets converted into php file and gets
   uploaded on the server.
2. On the download part, I'm using `ftp_get`. I want the file to get
       downloaded to my laptop. However it is getting saved on the server
       itself with the whole path which i specify in `$fileToy`. No error
       displayed, also file doesn't get downloaded. Here for simplicity
       I've given the path directly considering I've uploaded a .txt file.

Please help for general case(any file format).

Here is my code

```
if ((isset($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'])))
    $myfile = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
else echo "upload not possible";

$fileFrom = $myfile;              
$fileTo = 'photos/'. basename($myfile);     //photos is directory created on server
echo $fileTo;

$ftpObj -> uploadFile($fileFrom, $fileTo);

$fileFrom = $fileTo ;                            # The location on the server
$fileToy = 'Downloads\techppr.txt' ;            # Local dir to save to

// *** Download file
$ftpObj->downloadFile($fileFrom, $fileToy);

public function uploadFile ($fileFrom, $fileTo)
{
    // *** Set the transfer mode
    $asciiArray = array('txt', 'csv');
    $extension = end(explode('.', $fileFrom));
    if (in_array($extension, $asciiArray)) {
       $mode = FTP_ASCII;      
    } else {
    $mode = FTP_BINARY;
    }

    // *** Upload the file
    $upload = ftp_put($this->connectionId, $fileTo, $fileFrom, $mode);
}

public function downloadFile ($fileFrom, $fileTo)
{

    // *** Set the transfer mode
    $asciiArray = array('txt', 'csv');
    $extension = end(explode('.', $fileFrom));
    if (in_array($extension, $asciiArray)) {
        $mode = FTP_ASCII;      
    } else {
        $mode = FTP_BINARY;
    }
    if (ftp_get($this->connectionId, $fileTo, $fileFrom, $mode, 0)) {
        return true;
        $this->logMessage(' file "' . $fileTo . '" successfully downloaded');
    } else {
         return false;
        $this->logMessage('There was an error downloading file "' . $fileFrom . '" to "' . $fileTo . '"');
     }
}
```